# Getting values from JTable cell

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable

I made a column editable in Jtable.

I want old values from a cell when I have finished editing a cell

Comment: " I want values from a cell when entering into it like key releasedEvent". You mean: "I want old values from a cell when I have finished editing a cell"?

Comment: well once you have finished editing a cell, then the new value replaces the old. How do you think this should work?

Comment: i have finished editing of cell at row and column 1 and When i press enter key then focus goes to row 2 of same column.Here i want value of cell at column and row 1.

Comment: the OLD value? or the new value? If you want the old then you need an event like onClick, or onFocus, and then you just store the old value

Comment: I have scenario when i enter value in cell in accordance to value of cell my text-field value should be change.means i typed 1 then there should be 1 in text-field..after 1 in same cell 12 then text-field should be 12 so on like keyreleased event on textfield

Comment: paste some code in your question and ill have a look at it

Answer (score 26):

You can get the value by using

`table.getModel().getValueAt(row_index, col_index);`

where `table` is the name of the table and it will return an `Object`

Go through this [Getting cell value](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/GetCellValues.shtml). It may be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks but i am not getting last inserted value in cell when focus goes to next cell

Comment: This is to get the value of the cell at the time of displaying, not current time. So if u want to achieve that reproduce the table temporarily and get from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`TableCellListener`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/), like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124742/261156). It uses a `PropertyChangeEvent` to keep track of the old and new values.

Answer (score 1):

You also could create your own implementation of a TableModel and override the setValueAt method to keep track of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `TableModelListener` to your TableModel. Whenever an event fires you can updated the contents of your text field with the new value in the cell.